# ClassCastException cannot be cast to class X and Y are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I have a class called `ControllerConfiguration` where I add these two beans to the ApplicationContext:

```java
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ConnectorFittingController connectorFittingController() throws IOException {
        return loadController(ConnectorFittingController.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ConnectorFittingResultController connectorFittingResultController() throws IOException {
        return loadController(ConnectorFittingResultController.class);
    }
```

Now the following exception gets thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class de.some.project.controller.connectorfitting.ConnectorFittingResultController cannot be cast to class de.some.project.controller.connectedconnectors.ConnectedConnectorsController (de.some.project.controller.connectorfitting.ConnectorFittingResultController and de.some.project.controller.connectedconnectors.ConnectedConnectorsController are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at de.some.project.controller.ControllerConfiguration.connectedConnectorsController(ControllerConfiguration.java:156)
    at de.some.project.controller.ControllerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a944412.CGLIB$connectedConnectorsController$3(<generated>)
    at de.some.project.controller.ControllerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a944412$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$18aa65ce.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at de.some.project.controller.ControllerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a944412.connectedConnectorsController(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 62 more
```

This makes no sense for because I never try anywhere to cast to one of these classes.
I read in other questions that this has something to do with the spring developer tools. But I don't use them in my project.

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>private.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.32</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description></description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.harawata</groupId>
            <artifactId>appdirs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>testfx-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.16-alpha</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Edit:**
This is the `loadController` method.

```java
    /**
     * Uses {@link FXMLLoader} to load the view for a presenter. The FXML file name
     * is derived from the class name. The presenters root is set to the loader's
     * root. If a similarly named CSS file exists, it is added to the presenters
     * style sheets. The resource bundle is set using the same derived name.
     * 
     * @param clazz The Presenter class to load the FXML for.
     * @return The Presenter, i.e. the views controller.
     *
     * @throws IOException If the XML file can't be loaded.
     */
    protected <C extends AbstractHarconController<T>, T extends Parent> C loadController(Class<C> clazz)
            throws IOException {

        String derivedXmlName = deriveXMLName(clazz);

        try (InputStream fxmlStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(derivedXmlName)) {
            LOGGER.info("DerivedXMLName: {}", derivedXmlName);

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            try {
                loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(deriveBundleName(clazz)));
            } catch (MissingResourceException mre) {
                // Missing resource is ok, only log it for tracability, continue as normal
                LOGGER.trace("Unable to load resource bundle for {}: {}", deriveBundleName(clazz), mre.getMessage());
                LOGGER.trace("", mre);
            } // try

            loader.load(fxmlStream);
            addCSSIfAvailable(loader.getRoot(), clazz);

            return loader.getController();
        } // try
    }
```

Comment: How is the method `loadController` defined?

Comment: @PatriciaNicoleOpetina I added the method :)

Comment: Off-topic: It looks like you are trying to manage your FXML controllers as Spring beans. Just note that (unless I'm missing something) I don't think this code will do that; the controllers will be instantiated directly by invoking their no-argument constructors and Spring will be unaware of them. Consequently resource injection, etc., won't work in your controllers. You need a controller factory on the `FXMLLoader` that hooks into Spring.

Comment: Hey @James_D . Thanks for your comment! Yes I do manage all FXML controllers as beans but that solution actually works. Our convention is, that the FXML-file needs to have the same name as the controller, the controller needs to be set in FXML as well and the root node of each FXML-file needs to be "root" (that is defined in the AbstractHarconController).

Comment: I think my comment still stands, though; with the code you have, the controllers are going to be instantiated by the `FXMLLoader`. They're not going to be instantiated (or managed) by Spring.

Comment: Hm they get not managed by Spring until they get configured manually like shown in my question. The `ControllerConfiguration` class is annotated with @Configuration.
After that they can (for example) be @Autowired everywhere. Not sure if i fully understand you comment. I am just starting with Spring.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Your Spring configuration essentially uses the `FXMLLoader` to create the controllers, then exposing them as Spring Beans. That works, but doesn't it mean the only way to access the views is to request them from the controller? That kind of breaks MVC/MVP, though it's a minor point. I prefer to approach it the other way around: letting the `FXMLLoader` get the controllers from Spring.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for the heads up! That sounds reasonable, is there an code example for letting the FXMLLoader get the controllers from Spring? I kind if understand the idea but wouldn't be able to code it atm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238634/discussion-between-philipp-and-james-d).

Comment: Here's a code example: https://github.com/james-d/SpringFXExample (a little old, but should show the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I defined the wrong controller in the corresponding FXML-file...

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Stack Trace, Error is coming from the place
de.some.project.controller.ControllerConfiguration.connectedConnectorsController(ControllerConfiguration.java:156)

You are referencing a wrong place I think.
Actually Error say you try to convert ConnectorFittingResultController class to ConnectedConnectorsController class at ControllerConfiguration.java:156
Please check that point.